# How to modify Rxjs event to listen keys pressed?

Tags: angular, rxjs

I use [this](https://notiz.dev/blog/simple-rxjs-keyboard-shortcuts) RXjs solution for hotkeys.

I use this condition to catch leftSfidt + m keys:

`const toogle$ = shortcut([KeyCode.ShiftLeft, KeyCode.KeyM]);`

Problem is it works only when I press and unpress these keys. How to modify this example in case when user pressed keys and keep them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use from event keydown

```js
const { fromEvent, filter } = rxjs;

fromEvent(document, 'keydown').pipe(
  filter(e => e.shiftKey && e.keyCode === 77)
).subscribe(e => console.log('We got a shift m'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/7.8.0/rxjs.umd.min.js"></script>
Click here to get the snippet's iframe into focus before it will start getting keyboard events
```